# What is the real alternative of read_stream to read facebook news feeds?

Tags: c#, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

What is the real alternative of read_stream to read the news feeds from Facebook ? 
The answer is usually users_posts , but can the latter fetch the news feeds ? - for instance like the suggested posts on the timeline -

In other words I am trying to know if there is a way through the new Graph API to pull ads like what we used to do with FQL and read_stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible any longer. `user_posts` is the thing most similar to the old `read_stream` permission.

Comment: Then how tools like social ad Ninja are able to pull the Ads from facebook profiles?

Comment: Ads is something completely different... What has this to do with access to a user's newsfeed? Read the docs if you don't believe me. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview

Comment: An Ad is nothing but a news feed shown on the timeline of the facebook's user account regardless of it's placement ( right or middle), so it is not something completely different , if you can fetch news feed , you can fetch the Ads..

Comment: That's not correct what you're saying. It's actually is very different, because there are two completely different APIs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis

Comment: Dear Tobi , the marketing API is used to manage and create Ads and can't by any means used to fetch ads from the user's home page, if you think there is a way (ANY WAY) to get the ads, I would be grateful to you.

Comment: I don't get what you're after. It'll not work anyway.